# Was there a spurt of new users associated with launch?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I know Webapps garnered quite a few new users in the few days site left beta.  Is the same thing happening on gaming?

Answer (score 2):

Every user starting at [3920](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3920/pmg) is a registration from the point the new design was launched; the current number is **18 users**. If you want to use something less on-the-dot, [3926](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3926/cagdas) is the start of today; the current number is **12 users**.

So, yes, since the launch we have gotten a bunch of new users. Of them, the majority are associated with another site, but there's at least 3 who are freshly new.

If we want to measure with the few days that Web Apps had, then let's revisit this after a few days from launch and see some better numbers.

Comment: Let's not forget the staff hasn't actually tweeted about the launch... yet. Except for [Kevin Montrose](http://twitter.com/kevinmontrose/status/26579083728), that is.

Comment: I suspect that the post on joelonsoftware contributed a lot also, even though the blog isn't officially active, I think there's still a large audience.  Hopefully we'll get mentioned there as well.

Comment: As an update, since this post **23 more users** have registered with the site, with a roughly even spread between SE veterans and completely new users. So, aye, I'm quite certain it'll be some time before we can put down some kind of concrete measurement.

Comment: Care to re-run that now?

Comment: @CRoss Up to the point I started writing this, there have been **124 users** since the launch, or **118 users** if we're using the 3926 startpoint. That yields **83 new users** since the last update. It stills seems to be a roughly even spread between SE veterans and new users, and both kinds of users are also participating.